# How can I reduce the build time for a .NET Core application using Docker and Kaniko?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, kaniko

I have following Dockerfile in my .NET Core 2.2 console application.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TaikunBillerPoller.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "TaikunBillerPoller.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "TaikunBillerPoller.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TaikunBillerPoller.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TaikunBillerPoller.dll"]
```

My .dockerignore file looks like

```
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/azds.yaml
**/charts
**/bin
**/obj
**/Dockerfile
**/Dockerfile.develop
**/docker-compose.yml
**/docker-compose.*.yml
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
**/.toolstarget
```

We are using GitLab and Kaniko for building gitlab-ci.yml file.

This console application takes 7 minutes to build, but another application written in the Go language takes 40 seconds.

How might I reduce the build time for this application?

Comment: That's what happens if you try to use Microsoft software in a container. The go application, if it's on alpine, will produce a container that's a couple of hundred kilobytes in size. The MS app must be upwards of 2GB. That's going to take a long time just to move around the network, let alone build. MS is slow and bloated and should be avoided at all cost :) Having said that, 7 minutes isn't bad -- is this a real operational concern?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I don't know maybe possible to reduce time using some small images from docker.hub maybe I am not using correct ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first FROM line is completely unused.  Instead change your `FROM base` line to `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-stretch-slim`

This issue may be due to the fact that Kaniko **/someDir .dockerignore patterns are not properly observed.  I'm noticing that /obj, /bin, .idea (rider) and .git folders are all being copied.

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/1396

You are also not using the alpine based sdk and runtime images.

In the `dotnet restore command` you can use the `--no-cache` flag because docker layer cacheing will take care of that.

`dotnet publish` does a build so you can skip calling `dotnet build`.   If you want to perform testing you can call `dotnet test` then

You are explicitly calling `dotnet restore` so in all subsequent `dotnet` commands you can use the `--no-restore` option.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine AS base
#Add whatever tools you need to the base image
RUN apk add --update --no-cache git bash curl zip; \
    export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"; \
    dotnet tool install --global dotnet-xunit-to-junit --version 1.0.2

FROM base AS restore
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TaikunBillerPoller.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore --no-cache "TaikunBillerPoller.csproj"
COPY . .

FROM restore as publish
ARG VERSION="0.0.0"
RUN dotnet test "TaikunBillerPoller.csproj" --configuration Release --no-restore
RUN dotnet publish "TaikunBillerPoller.csproj" --output /app --configuration Release --no-restore /p:Version=$VERSION

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-alpine AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TaikunBillerPoller.dll"]
```

On a 2015 Mac I have an asp.net microservice that builds, tests, publishes and creates a beanstalk_bundle zip using a normal `docker build` with the following times:

- 51s No cache
- 22s Code change
- <1s No code change (pipeline yml change)

Kaniko adds overhead because layer caching is done remotely to some repository (typically).
This time is going to depend a lot on how you have your Kaniko cache and mounted volumes configured.  Here is something I use on my local machine for debugging.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Assuming this is either not an ephemeral machine, or the ephemeral machine
# maps the cache directory to permanent volume.
# We cache images into the local machine
# so that the Kaniko container, which is ephemeral, does not have to pull them each time.
docker run -v $(pwd):/workspace gcr.io/kaniko-project/warmer:latest \
        --cache-dir=/workspace/cache \
        --image=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine \
        --image=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-alpine
docker run -it --rm \
        -v `pwd`:/workspace \
        -v `pwd`/kaniko-config.json:/kaniko/.docker/config.json:ro \
        -v `pwd`/reports:/reports \
        -v `pwd`/beanstalk_bundle:/beanstalk_bundle \
        gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest \
        --dockerfile "buildTestPublish.Dockerfile" \
        --destination "registry.gitlab.com/somePath/theImageName:theVersion" \
        --skip-unused-stages \
        --cache \
        --cache-dir=/workspace/cache \
        --verbosity=trace
```